# Hyperledger Fabric EventHub has been shut down [Write operations stopped]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am facing an issue and because of this issue all the write operations are stopped. Neither write operation on couchdb are working nor in ledger.

It shows me an error that `EventHub has been shutdown`.

I have to restart all the peers to fix this.

Can any one explain why it is happening? How can I prevent this error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you resolve it ? How did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why it was happening in [my case](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/write_first_app.html) were that fabric-samples/bin folder was removed and it could not find cryptogen inside the bin. Also that invoke.js and all other references to localhost needed to be replaced by docker container's new given IP. The orphan containers needed to be reset and node.js needed to be updated too.

I run inside the fabric-samples this command

```
git checkout
```

It confirmed all the files I had updated by saying:

> M       fabcar/enrollAdmin.js
>
> M       fabcar/invoke.js
>
> M       fabcar/query.js
>
> M       fabcar/registerUser.js
>
> Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/release-1.1'.

Then copied the folder fabric-samples/bin from my old source. Then I entered into fabric-samples/first-network and generated the network artifacts again

```
./byfn.sh down
./byfn.sh -m generate
```

Then I entered fabcar and run

```
docker network prune
npm install
./startFabric.sh node
node enrollAdmin.js
node registerUser.js
```

Then after updating the invoke.js with new data and fcn function name createCar

```
node invoke.js
```

Output:

> Store path:C:\Users\John\fabric-samples\fabcar\hfc-key-store
>
> Successfully loaded user1 from persistence Assigning transaction_id:
>
> 7573040d7bf4c3b2f5599f50650620de2ff81afcd9c153e1cc6187704d91b2bf
>
> Transaction proposal was good
>
> Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - 200, message - "OK"
>
> The transaction has been committed on peer 192.168.99.100:7053
>
> Send transaction promise and event listener promise have completed
>
> Successfully sent transaction to the orderer.
>
> Successfully committed the change to the ledger by the peer

Then querying all cars using the original query.js

```
node query.js
```

Output:

> Store path:C:\Users\John\fabric-samples\fabcar\hfc-key-store
>
> Successfully loaded user1 from persistence Query has completed,
>
> checking results Response is  [{"Key":"CAR0","Record":
>
> {"color":"blue","docType":"car","make":"Toyota","model":"Prius","owner":"Tomoko"}},
>
> {"Key":"CAR1","Record":
>
> {"color":"red","docType":"car","make":"Ford","model":"Mustang","owner":"Brad"}},
>
> {"Key":"CAR10","Record":
>
> {"color":"Red","docType":"car","make":"Chevy","model":"Volt","owner":"John"}},
>
> {"Key":"CAR11","Record":
>
> {"color":"White","docType":"car","make":"Chevy","model":"Volt","owner":"Ahsan"}},...]